# How to display greek characters?

Tags: html

Between the english text in my HTML page I would like to insert these characters:

> πσ⌠ρα

When I copy and paste it, this appears: ?????

My page already includes `<meta charset="utf-8" />`.

How can I get it displayed correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can insert the entity code for each character you want to display into the HTML. For example, `&zeta;` will display ζ.

To write πσ⌠ρα use the codes:

```
&#960; &#963; &#8992; &#961; &#945;
```

For a full list of characters there are many resources available, here's [one](http://webdesign.about.com/od/localization/l/blhtmlcodes-gr.htm).

Comment: Thank you but I can't find the character ⌠ on that list.